# How to get people to answer questions?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get attention for my old, unanswered questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-my-old-unanswered-questions)

How can you get more traffic onto your questions? I would like something answered, which no-one has managed yet. What should I do?

Comment: The duplicate is about old questions, but it also applies to new ones too.

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head, the obvious ones would be:

- Offer a bounty on your question
- Tweet your question to your followers
- Post a link on your Facebook

Alternatively, maybe your question needs to be reworded or more content/examples edited in to it.  If a question is easy to read and the problem is easy to understand then more people are likely to answer it.  Also ensure that it is tagged correctly.